# How to redirect to new page as well as export a file to pdf at a time on click of button in jsf

Tags: redirect, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 6.1. On click of a button i want to print a pdf file and redirect to a new page at the same time. My code is like this :

```
<h:form id="panelMain" target="_blank">
        <p:commandButton id="cmdPrint" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" action="#{employeeMB.redirectToPrint}" ajax="false"
                                        style="width:100px; margin-right:5px" 
                                        value="Print"  process="cmdPrint"/>
                                        
</h:form>
```

In managed bean my code is like this:

```
public void redirectToPrint(){
printToPdf();
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/pages/hr/EmployeeRegistration.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Export to PDF file is success but redirect to new page does not occur. Where i am making mistake? Is it due to ajax = false?

Comment: FYI PrimeFaces 6.5 does not exist.